# Reporting Services Configuration Manager (2008 R2): Provider Load Failure error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-express

I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on my 64-bit Windows 7 machine. I then ran Reporting Services Configuration Manager and it came up with a dialog that has my machine name filled in and a Find button (to find the instances on that machine). When I click on Find, I get a "Provider Load Failure" dialog.

I've read elsewhere that this might have something to do with ReportingServicesWMI.dll not being in the right path. I do not have this file in either the System32 or SysWOW64 folders. I do have it in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared.

%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem is in my PATH and does exist on disk. The Windows Management Instrumentation Service is running.

How can I resolve this problem so I can configure SSRS on this machine?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I upgraded to a newer version of SQL Server. When using the Reporting Services Configuration Manager for the old SQL Server version, I received the error, "Provider Load Failure error"

My solution was to simply use the new RS Configuration Manager that came with the SQL Server upgrade version.

Comment: Yes, I have this problem solved by this way. Confusing enough that you have 2 tools with the same name though.

Answer (score 0):

The provider has a dependency on C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\framedyn.dll. Is that file there? You could also try copying it into C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared as well.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I fixed it by uninstalling and reinstalling. I'll keep your idea in mind if we should run into it again on another machine.